# Onsen UI Navigator from Jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

i had a navigator with interacts with some pages. I am trying to use jquery instead onf angular. Googling i had found a solution to modify the selected page html with this code:

```
ons.ready (function (){
    $(document).on('ons-navigator:postpush', 'ons-navigator', function(event) {
        //Do something
    });
});
```

How could i set up this for an specific html page(because the code above is for all page the navigator changes to).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `postpush` event in Onsen UI docs: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#event-postpush

There are useful parameters you can use for that such as `event.enterPage` and `event.leavePage`.

Also, you can get the current page with `myNav.getCurrentPage()`and the entire page stack with `myNave.getPages()`. More info in the previous link.

Hope it helps!

**Edit:**

Looks like the original event is wrapped in another object.

```
ons.ready (function (){
  $(document).on('ons-navigator:postpush', 'ons-navigator', function(event) {
      event = event.originalEvent;

      // Do something
      console.log('From',event.leavePage.name, 'to', event.enterPage.name);
   });
});
```

Working here http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/doMdbw

Comment: Hi, tjanks for your answer. The problem is that when i use jquery the "event" parameter doensn't have the attributes enterPage or leavePage. I was looking for a onsen ui with jquery tutorial. Could you help me, please? Regards

Comment: I cannot provide a jQuery+OnsenUI guide since I don't use jQuery that much, but I have updated the answer with a workaround. Hope this helps you.